# How to run the javascript script on all the pages of domain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, salesforce

I am working on salesforce. Some pages are totally inaccessible i.e., I cannot add any javascript in those pages. But there are some pages where I can add some javascript and these both pages are on the same domain. Can I in some way store the script in a cookie or local storage or something, so that when the page(which is accessible) loads I can store the script and execute it when the pages which are inaccessible loads?

Please help!!

Regards
Sameer

Comment: It sounds like what you are trying to do should be prevented by every browser with any security standards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No that is not possible, unless you have access in some way to modify what is shown on the page.  If it were possible, hackers would just deposit cookies on anyone's machine, corrupting the internet.

Comment: Hey now, we all know the Internet is already corrupted. Give credit to the 1995 porn realm.

Answer (score 3):

You can't run your own JS on SalesForce.com but you can certainly use SF's [API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm) and [SOQL](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm) to grab whatever data you need to your server and run your JS on that page

Comment: I have added some javascript in the sidebar component. But unfortunately these sidebar components are not enabled on the reports tab. But I have a requirement to run the javascript on the contents of the reports tab.. ANy idea how to go about it??